# How to unit test Onclick function in react component using enzyme and tape?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I have the following component and I am using enzyme and tape to test react components.

```
class Modal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    this.onAccountChange = this.onAccountChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
     selectedAccount: props.accounts[0].id;
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {accounts} = this.props;

    return <div>
             <select className="account-selector" onChange={this.onAccountChange}>
                {accounts.map(account => <option key={account.id} value={account.id}>{account.desc}</option>)}
             </select>
           </div>;
  }

   onAccountChange(e){
     const {value: selectedAccount} = e.target;
     this.setState({selectedAccount});
   }
```

How could I got about testing the OnChange in the select element and the function it calls onAccountChange?